# Probability that explosive random walk $X\to\gamma X+\epsilon$ with $\gamma>1$, always stays positive

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-walks

Let $\{\epsilon_t\}_{t\ge0}$ be a sequence of iid random variables with full support. Let $\delta\ge0$ and $\gamma>1$. Then set $X_0 = \delta$ and define for $t\ge0$:
$$
X_{t+1} = \gamma X_{t} + \epsilon_t.
$$
For such a random walk we have $|X_t|\rightarrow\infty$ almost surely.

**Question:** I am interested in upper and lower bounds on the probability
$$
P(X_t > 0 \quad \forall t\ge0 \mid X_0 = \delta),
$$
i.e., the probability that the process never becomes negative.

I believe that I am not the first person to ask this question or a similar one. Can someone help me or point me to literature that deals with questions like this? The answer for $\delta=0$ would already be great.

Comment: Martingale methods ought to give something?

Comment: I looked into similar (more general) problem in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5152v1.pdf) some time ago. For general Markovian dynamics I applied Lyapunov-like functions, there are a couple of references in the text on how to find them. In your case it may be harder unless you have a positive drift, however I think you can use the fact that $\gamma > 1$ to compensate for it for $X$ large enough (where you need the convergence to infinity).